# Como pasar un atributo mediante un v-for a una lista en vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Uso la directiva v-for para iterar los elementos de un array de objetos y los imprimo en una lista. Como puedo pasar un atributo al href que sea un texto fijo mas el id del elemento de la lista

```
          <li v-for="(item, index) in searchProduct" :key="index">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="frontoffice/images/product/other/s05.jpg" alt>
        </div>
        <div class="info-product">
          <div class="name">
            <a :href="products/item.id" title="">{{item.name}}</a>
          </div>
          <div class="price">
            <span class="sale">$50.00</span>
            <span class="regular">$2,999.00</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya probaste de esta manera?

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in searchProduct" :key="index">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="frontoffice/images/product/other/s05.jpg" alt>
    </div>
    <div class="info-product">
      <div class="name">
        <a v-bind:href="'products/' + item.id" title="">{{item.name}}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="price">
        <span class="sale">$50.00</span>
        <span class="regular">$2,999.00</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```